# Move Android Studio project directory up

Tags: android, android-studio

Right now I have a project in the equivalent of a/b/. However, I want to move the project directory from b/ to a/. a/ currently has nothing in it except for b/. Do I need to change any settings, or should I just move everything from b/ to a/, remove b/, and import a/ as another project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply moving the files and then importing as another project will work. Make sure you do `Files-> Invalidate Cache / Restart` so that directory paths are updated, and caches are cleared.

Comment: Thank you. But should I do this before or after I move/import the files/project?

Comment: Do it after you move the files and import the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should do what @Anuraag-Vaidya said, after that, you should clean your project (Build\Clean Project) and THEN it will work.